# How to Change "Shell" Color Scheme in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I selected Language -> S -> Shell for a Linux shell script I'm viewing/editing. Some portions have this red font with blue background which is hard for me to read. To change this, I went to Settings -> Style Configurator, but to my dismay "Shell" is not listed as one of the languages.

1. Why is "Shell" not listed?
2. If "Shell" is not listed, how do I change the color scheme for "Shell"?
3. How do I find what kind of text is marked with red font and blue background/highlight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try, from the Menu Bar,

```
Settings > Style Configurator > bash
```

If that doesn't work I'd reach out to the n++ forums, https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/

Comment: Thanks - that helped. I found the style in question is a "HERE Q" - I have never heard of that. Do you know if HERE Q is the same as a here document?